# Avoid calling a scalar function multiple times in an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to modify the following `UPDATE` statement so that the scalar function is called only once, not twice?

```
UPDATE a
    SET SomeField = b.SomeField
    FROM TableA AS a
    JOIN TableB b ON b.Link = a.Link
    WHERE b.CostMin <= @Cost * dbo.OneScalarFunction(@CurrencyFrom, b.Currency)
        AND b.CostMax >= @Cost * dbo.OneScalarFunction(@CurrencyFrom, b.Currency)
```

**P.S.** Using the `BETWEEN` operator does not help - SQL Server calls the scalar function twice anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is often significantly more performant, but requires you to change the scalar function to an inline table valued function.

```
UPDATE
  a
SET
  SomeField = b.SomeField
FROM
  TableA AS a
CROSS APPLY
  dbo.oneInlineTableValuedFunction(@CurrencyFrom, e.Currency) AS ITVF
INNER JOIN
  TableB b
    ON b.Link = a.Link
WHERE
      b.CostMin <= @Cost * ITVF.exchangeRate
  AND b.CostMax >= @Cost * ITVF.exchangeRate
```

Although table valued functions return tables, you ***can*** choose to retun just one row with one field.  Then you're using it effectively as a scalar function - But, you get all the benefits of how SQL Server can optimise the query above...
  - If the TVF is Inline *(and not multi-statement)*
  - The TVF gets expanded out into the query
  - The result is performance dramatiaclly better than scalar functions

Example Inline Table Valued Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.oneInlineTableValuedFunction (
                      @currencyFrom   VARCHAR(32),
                      @currencyTo     VARCHAR(32)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
  SELECT
    exchangeRate
  FROM
    dbo.someTable
  WHERE
        currencyFrom = @currencyFrom
    AND currencyTo   = @currencyTo
)
```

*Deliberately trivial*

One example post about this:  [scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)

If you seach the web for `INLINE CROSS APPLY SCALAR FUNCTION PERFORMANCE` I'm sure you'll get a whole lot more.

Comment: Thank you. It seems there's no other choice but to give up scalar functions in favour of table-valued functions.

Comment: @10p - They *are* massively more efficient when applied across an entire data-set.

Answer (score 5):

Try the **BETWEEN** operator.

```
WHERE functionCall(..) BETWEEN minValue AND maxValue
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: Good thought. That might get expanded out to `<=` and `>=` in practice though.

Comment: SQL Server calls the scalar function twice anyway, I guess it's just a different notation, so this suggestion doesn't really solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

You could try using BETWEEN (as below), although you'd need to test it as I've got a sneaking suspicion the database might split this out to execute it as >= and <= anyway..

```
UPDATE a
    SET SomeField = b.SomeField
    FROM TableA AS a
    JOIN TableB b ON b.Link = a.Link
    WHERE  @Cost * dbo.OneScalarFunction(@CurrencyFrom, e.Currency) BETWEEN b.CostMin AND b.CostMax
```